# Targets variable as public not defined in CameraControl.cs

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I need to do this (which is done in red) ,but there is no targets variable I am following the Unity Tanks tutorial for controlling the camera movement. Near the end of the tutorial it asks to drop the Tank Gameobject onto the public variable 'Targets' of the Camera Control Script, but on the dropdown menu of the Camera Control Script in Unity there is no 'Targets'. I can see from the tutorial video where it should be, but it's not there on my computer.
I tried to make **public GameObject Targets;** and dropped tank over it but it didn't work.
Please tell me what should I do ?

[image]

Comment: Please post a picture of the scene that shows where the target is supposed to go then post your whole script.

Comment: I have pasted the picture , which tells what I need to do ,please check it please

Comment: According to the picture, you successfully attached the transform of the Tank to the slot which is an array. Now you need to post your code. Also, if you want this to be solved easily, post the link of the tutorial too so that I can compare it with your current code and tell you what you are missing.

Comment: https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/projects/tanks-tutorial/camera-control
this is the link of the tutorial , below is the code. Please check this @Programmer

Comment: I am using the same code , but when I run it , it doesn't display this variable , so that I can put tank on it as target variable.

Comment: I don't understand you. When I said post a picture, I meant picture of your scene not picture of a video in VLC. I just realized that the picture you posted is a picture of the tutorial. I need picture from your scene! The only way to find out what you are doing wrong is if you post a picture then post your current code so that someone here can compare them.

Comment: Really sorry , I didn't understand , really really sorry @Programmer

Comment: That's fine. You solved the problem. Accept yes's answer since it solved your problem. It's a way of saying thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you just copy and paste the finished code?

because right after where he says drop the tank, you are going to add the HideInInspector attribute, which, as the name suggest, hides the field in the inspector.

i didnt watch the full video, just read the transcript, but you should be good if you simply remove [HideInInspector] from the target field.

the line in question

```
[HideInInspector] public Transform[] m_Targets; // All the targets the camera needs to encompass.
```

Comment: Thank you sooooo much !! It just worked.
It's my first game in unity ,so learner , anyways thanks alot.

Comment: @Raja Accept this as the answer if this solved your problem.

Comment: I didn't have much reputation to vote for this answer. But , this solved my Problem +1 for you.
@Programmer you can vote this ans.

Comment: @Raja You don't need points to accept answer. You only need points to vote. Click the check button on this answer to accept the answer. Its not my answer but I think this guy deserves the point. Look at the picture in the link below on the red circled icon to see where to click. http://i.stack.imgur.com/uqJeW.png

Comment: Good for you @yes :)